# Rotating Arrow between Two Points of Degrees

Tags: javascript, function, variables, event-listener

This is the fake gauge I want the arrow to work on

[image: This is the fake gauge I want the arrow to work on]

I want the red line/pointer to randomly generate between 0 - 100% humidity.

HTML:

```js
//variables 

let hygrometerHand = document.querySelector("#hygrometerHand");
const button = document.querySelector("#button");
let hygrometerAngle = 0;
hygrometerHand = 0;

//function

function generateResult() {
  let min = -100;
  let max = 95;
  let x = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  hygrometerHand = x;
  hygrometerHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hygrometerHand}deg)`;
}

//button and event listener to generate moisture reading

button.addEventListener("click", generateResult);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="clock-container">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z72xm.jpg" />
      <div id="hygrometerHand"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button id="button">Click here</button>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help with this! I know the answer is probably going to be very simple but its my second week of learning JS in a bootcamp and my mind is p overloaded.

Thank you!

Comment: `hygrometerHand = x;` you're overwriting the variable which stores your HTML element with the _number_ `x`, then on the next line, you try to use `hygrometerHand` as a number and as an element - it can only be one, not both

Comment: Thank you so much Nick! :) I knew it would some obvious issue. however when you are a newbie, nothing seems obvious. I've gone from not knowing any JS two weeks ago, to diving into the deep sea of JS. Loving it but do find that I make errors like that when I'm in a state of frustration.

Comment: You:  `let hygrometerHand = document.querySelector("#hygrometerHand");`  Then moments later, also you: `hygrometerHand = 0;`  You were holding your div element in `hygrometerHand`.  It's like you were holding a 100 dollar bill in your hand on a windy day, then you opened that same hand to pick up a potato, then you wonder where your 100 dollar bill went.

Comment: @Max no worries, your code is looking pretty good too for only two weeks, nice work . Debugging and finding errors is part of the learning experience and will become easier as you continue. Using `console.log()` or your browser's debugger to ensure variables are what you think they are can be helpful too.